# Gulp html templating

Tags: html, templates, gulp, gulp-plugin

Has anyone knew any "gulp" plugin which compiles(bundles) different files with something .html extension into one file? Or which closer to what I am trying to 
achieve?

ex.

```
      build
        |- html
            |- header.html
            |- footer.html
            |- main-section.html
        |- index.html
      dist 
        |- index.html(result)
```

on index.html file on `build`

```
      ... some meta tags
      ...
      somewhere inside body tag
```

`/* I want something like */
  require('build/html/header.html);
  require('build/html/main-section.html);
  require('build/html/footer.html);
</pre>`

And the output would be the html inside of those files. 
Where also each of those files(header, ...) have something require also.

P.S. Can someone list of them with links, please? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject#injecting-files-contents). From the README at github:

> In order to inject files contents you have to provide custom transform function, that will return file contents as string. You also have to omit {read: false} option of gulp.src in this case. Example below shows how to inject contents of html partials into head of index.html:

```
    gulp.src('./src/index.html')
  .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['./src/partials/head/*.html']), {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:head:{{ext}} -->',
    transform: function (filePath, file) {
      // return file contents as string 
      return file.contents.toString('utf8')
    }
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
```

And in your ./src/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My index</title>
  <!-- inject:head:html -->
  <!-- contents of html partials will be injected here -->
  <!-- endinject -->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see, so some one have created such, thanks. I appreciate your answer, but the syntax is kinda odd. Do you know anything else? with one line syntax? something like(ex. php) <?php include('file.html') ?>

Answer (score 0):

A better one might be [gulp-inject-multiple-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject-multiple-files).

In gulp file:

```
gulp.task('inject-files',function(){
 // begin injection 
  gulp.src('foo.html')
    .pipe(injectfiles('foo.html','parts'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('temp'));

});
```

In your index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My index</title>
  <!-- inject:head-->
  <!-- inject:footer-->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If this is for email templates, may I also recommend [Zurb/Inky](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/). They are quite easy to use and they don't break very often in outlook